# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript

```
var names = ["andy","amy","randy","ronaldo","nani"];

for(var i = 0;i<names.length;i++){
    console.log("My name is " . names[i]);
}
```

I wonder what's wrong here. why i cannot be zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript isn't PHP, and string concatenation here is being made via `+`, not a `.`:

```
var names = ["andy","amy","randy","ronaldo","nani"];

for(var i = 0;i<names.length;i++){
    console.log("My name is " + names[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because of the `.` in

```
console.log("My name is " . names[i]);
```

change it to comma (`,`) or plus (`+`) like this

```
console.log("My name is ", names[i]);
console.log("My name is " + names[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you confuse the `javascript` concatenation with `php`

var names = ["andy","amy","randy","ronaldo","nani"];

```
for(var i in names){
    console.log("My name is " + names[i]); // change . with + here
}
```

also you can minimize your loop with `var i in names`

check this http://jsfiddle.net/g96T8/